# TF10175: The team project does not exists

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I use visualstudio online for repository.
I removed [ProjectName] project from collecection of project
After that I got error only on one computer
TF10175: The [ProjectName] team project doesnot exist.

Any idea to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got rid of the message by deleting my Workspace.

**Note:** This will remove all your local mappings. Therefore you should checkin all changes before deleting it. After re-connecting to your TFS a new workspace will be created automatically.

To delete the workspace follow these steps:

1. In "Team Explorer" select "Pending Changes"
2. Beside the "Check In" button click on "Actions" and select "Manage Workspaces…"
3. Select the Workspace and press "Remove"

Answer (score 0):

In Team Explorer, press the "Connect to Team Projects" button, that looks like a plug. You should be able to un-select the deleted Team project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Source control explorer then click on workspace dropdown in the visual studio, you will find option "Workspaces" click on it. it will list the workspaces you have. click edit on your workspace , and delete the unneeded project from your workspace. it will work after that.

Answer (score 0):

I  was adding files/items to a newly created TFS/Agile project when I got this error message.

The TFS Project (source code) was mapped to c:\ABC but for some reason adding files from c:\AAB didn't work. I copied all files from c:\AAB to c:\ABC and then tried adding the items from the mapped folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because of a more basic problem.  I could not attach my solution to the team project because the names were different:

```
1. Bad Project Name: "Employee Travel" -> space between words
2. Fixed Project Name: "EmployeeTravel" -> matches solution name
```