# TF10175: The My Project team project does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I deleted a Team Project from Visual Studio Online. We were using the repository in source control with Visual Studio 2013.

Since deleting it, everytime I load up Visual Studio, I get the following message in general ouput:

```
The server returned the following error: The project with id '{myid}' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
```

And the following popup:

[image: The project with id does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.]

If I try to do ANYTHING source control related, I get the following error:

```
TF10175: The My Project team project does not exist.
```

[image: The team project does not exist]

I have removed the project from my "connected projects" in VS Team Explorer.  I have double checked that all my workspaces don't point to this repository.  I have even removed the project files from my PC and have restarted.

Comment: Have same problem, anyone found a solution?

Comment: @DNRN: Delete and recreate your workspace.

Comment: I hoped there was another way around :)

Comment: I did found another way, I had a lot of projects bound to my workspace. So didn't really like the idea just to delete it...

Comment: Duplicate of [TF10175: The team project does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801751/tf10175-the-team-project-does-not-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything.

What eventually worked was deleting my workspace and recreating it. A very frustrating issue.

Comment: I had to resort to this as well after attempting to remove the individual problem workspace, getting the same error that the project doesn't exist.  Did you have trouble re-mapping your workspaces?

Comment: @KyleJV:  I did not.  Just make sure you don't have any pending changes!

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution, so you can avoid deleting your whole workspace.

So the problem is, that a project is deleted from visualstudio.com before it deleted from a workspace. Why this ends up so bad, is another great question?

My workaround is as follow:

1. Create a new project with the same name as the troubled one.
2. From VS navigate to Team Explorer
3. From Team Explore: "Connect to Team Projects"
4. Select Team Projects...
5. Choose the troubled project added to the collection in 1
6. Click on the project and "Configure your workspace"
7. Map & Get
8. [Optional] I had issues because I had uncommitted changes in the project. I solved this by navigation to Pending Changes and undo and or excluded them from tfs.
9. Now it's possible to delete the workspace.
10. And now that the workspace is properly deleted, the project can once again be deleted from visualstudio.com
11. Restart Visual Studio

I don't know if any of the above steps can be omitted, this is how I accomplished to get rid of "TF10175", if anyone have optimized the procedure please leave a comment.

Comment: I know this was long time ago. I had the same issue today, the step 1 is very important. I created the project on TFS online with the same name, then I can undo, ... otherwise, it does not allow me undo.