# Error or Azure DevOps Error: TF402484 The personnel team project has been deleted

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

VS2019 with the most recent update... Version: 16.2.5

**Main error: TF402484 The personnel team project has been deleted**

**Also :  TF10175 The personel team project does not exist.**

As far as I understand so far, TFS new name seams to be "Azure DevOps". Some error say TFS while others "Azure DevOps" but it sounds like it is the same.

It got many errors in many projects (into at least 4 different solutions):

There is 3 to 4 kind of different dialog box errors, depending on where and what action I do related to TFS. All errors are about TF402484 error. The error is about a deleted project which nobody has deleted. Most of the time or always, the project has never been part of the solution.

I did not do anything else than updating my VS2019 to the most recent version.

I red: [Visual studio 2013 team project has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741455/visual-studio-2013-team-project-has-been-deleted)

About suggestion from previous link: "Undo any pending changes", yes it could seems to temporarily fix the bug BUT there is something that happen that put me in this situation, that seems to happen very often, intermitently and that's very anoying.

**In fact, why do I have many items from other projects (not in my current solution) that appear in the Pending Changes window of my current solution?**

**Starting Source Control Explorer give me many TF402484 DlgBox error (at least 4) and it show "Working..." and stay like that forever. IT just freeze.**

**Also, I'm using many instances of VS2019 open at the same time. Could it cause the error?**

What's going wrong??? What do I have to turn on/off or set, in order to prevent this behavior which is going to kill me in a near future?

Also, perhaps there is no connection, but the only other thing that also changed on my machine: I'm using Cobian Backup to do my backup and perhaps it touches (changes file time) to all or somes solution files.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error `the Undo any pending changes to that project or branches from that project in your local workspace.` indicate clearly. You could give a try with below two ways:

- **Delete the workspace** and created a new one, then check it again.

  `Team Explorer Home` --> Under `Solution` --> Click the arrow down
  behind `workspace` --> `Manage Workspaces`... --> Select the specific
  workspace then `Remove`

  **Note**: *This will remove all your local mappings. Therefore you should check in all changes before deleting it. or back up*
- Look at `Excluded Changes` section under `Pending Changes` and check
  if there are any files which belong to a **deleted folder**/deleted project. If yes,
  right click at the file name and choose **Undo**.

  [image]

Besides, you could try to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), which may do the trick.

Also reference this similar thread :

- [Visual Studio TFS: TF10175 During Add Solution To Source Control in
  Visual Studio How To Fix](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1024&fb_ref=Default)
- [TF10175: The team project does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801751/tf10175-the-team-project-does-not-exists)